# Почему нельзя создать constexpr std::error_category, ведь у этого класса есть constexpr конструктор?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17, метапрограммирование, constexpr

std::error_category имеет constexpr конструктор, но является абстрактным классом. Следовательно, его потомки не могут быть созданы constexpr. Зачем тогда конструктор error_category constexpr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот посмотрите эти ссылки объясняют почему

https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1116

https://www.cppstories.com/2021/constexpr-virtual/

Answer (score 3):

Ну, например, в VC++ запросто можно...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class concrete: public std::error_category
{
public:
    constexpr concrete():std::error_category(){}
    const char* name() const noexcept { return "concrete"; }
    std::string message( int ) const { return "concrete"s; };
};

int main()
{
    constexpr concrete c;
}
```

Comment: интересно, в clang13 для inux это вызывает ошибку компиляции

Comment: Не буду утверждать, кто прав, кто виноват... это к гуру в стандартах. Но не вижу, почему бы потомку `constexpr` самому не быть `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

Для constexpr нужен "Literal Type"

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const.
> Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized.

https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6

> A type is a literal type if it is:
> -- a possibly cv-qualified class type that has all of the following properties:
> it has a constexpr destructor ([dcl.constexpr]),
> all of its non-static non-variant data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types, and
> has at least one constexpr constructor

https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-10

а у `error_category` как не `constexpr` деструктор
https://eel.is/c++draft/syserr.errcat.overview

```
  class error_category {
  public:
    constexpr error_category() noexcept;
    virtual ~error_category();
```

поэтому её объект не может быть `constexpr`.

Однако можно использовать `constinit`.